# VueJS unknow custom element VueStripeCheckout

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This question has be answered already in many places. But none of them is works for me.
I installed [Vue stripe checkout](https://github.com/jofftiquez/vue-stripe-checkout) component in my project.

```
npm install vue-stripe-checkout --save
```

Then in the mainJS

```
import VueStripeCheckout from 'vue-stripe-checkout';

Vue.use(VueStripeCheckout, 'publishable-key-here');
```

Then inside my component

```
<vue-stripe-checkout
      ref="checkoutRef"
      :image="image"
      :name="name"
      :description="description"
      :currency="currency"
      :amount="amount"
      :allow-remember-me="false"
      @done="done"
      @opened="opened"
      @closed="closed"
      @canceled="canceled"
    ></vue-stripe-checkout>
```

[image]

I can't figureout why this could happen? Is this a bug in that libray or my code?

Comment: `Vue.use(VueStripeCheckout, {
  publishableKey: 'your-publishable-key'
});`

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar try that one too. It gave me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Answer (score 0):

since the component is seemingly not globally registered you can do it yourself

```
// in global.js

import VueStripeCheckout from 'vue-stripe-checkout'
Vue.use(VueStripeCheckout, 'publishable-key-here')

// global registration
Vue.component('vue-stripe-checkout',VueStripeCheckout)
```

Alernatively you could import it on a component level

```
// in somecomponent.vue

import VueStripeCheckout from 'vue-stripe-checkout'

export default {
  components: {
   'vue-stripe-checkout': VueStripeCheckout

   // or just - then you'll have to use it like <VueStripeCheckout>
   // VueStripeCheckout
  }
  ,props:[...]
  ,mounted()
```

in any case - checkout the [doc for components-registration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html)

---

Edit: having had a look at the source of the vue-stripe-checkout  [install fn](https://github.com/jofftiquez/vue-stripe-checkout/blob/master/src/index.js#L3) which is invoked by `Vue.use` - have you tried simply camelCase instead of snake-case:

```
<VueStripeCheckout
  ref="checkoutRef"
  :image="image"
```

Comment: Hi, I tried all of these after you answer. But still the result is the same.